# I was trying to build a recycler view that displays other items , snips are attached below

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My reputation is not up to the mark (as I am a newbie)  so that I could attach images but please visit the link

[this is the item that I want to display in my recycler view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJIs3.png)

[continued part of the item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYVh4.png)

[this is the recycler view where I want to display the item but on previewing by listitem only one item is visible and on running the app no item is visible (there is no error in the app anfd the addition in recycler view works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBfIE.png)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `match_parent` for height for your item view. One Item is filling all the space vertically.

Instead use:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in the constraint layout of your item view.

Comment: can you please suggest some course or how should i study android studio(kotlin)

Comment: To learn best practices always follow google developers official website. Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/campaign/learn) to learn kotlin.
Always vote up the answers you find best and mark them as best to appreciate. Thank you very much. Welcome to Kotlin :)